# Where did Apple reposition Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C class in Xcode 6?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, xcode6, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I've clicked on File -> New File in Xcode 6, yet there is no "Cocoa Touch" reference, nor is there an Objective-C class I can find. Using the latest public version of Xcode 6 (6.1 IIRC) and the iOS 8.1 SDK.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The Cocoa Touch Class template?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the Cocoa Touch Objective-C class template.

Comment: It is still there. If you go to File -> New -> File... on the left hand side the list is organized in two groups: iOS and OS X. Under iOS and then Source there is a Cocoa Touch Class. It looks exactly like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AVATJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

From inside a project, click on File/New File a drop down window will appear with Cocoa Touch Class being the first on the top left. When you set up your project you stipulate whether or not you intend to use Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: You can choose whether to use Objc or Swift on a per-class basis (or per-file) ;)